# Error with CTE . Could any one help me correct the below error

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I am writing below function to return Suffix passing name as parameter. I made possible cases of suffix exsist in name as common table expression and trying to compare with that. Could any one explain me the proper way of doing it.

```
  Alter function S (@Name varchar(100))
returns varchar(25)
as 
begin
declare @Suffix varchar(25)
WITH SearchTerms(Term)
     AS (SELECT ' I '
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ' II '
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ' III '
         UNION All
         SELECT ' MD '
          UNION All
         SELECT ' M.D '
          UNION All
         SELECT ' M.D. '
          UNION All
         SELECT ' D.O '
           UNION All
         SELECT ' D.O. '
           UNION All
         SELECT ' DO '
         )  ;

 set @Suffix = (select Term from SearchTerms where Charindex(Term,@Name) > 0)
 return @Suffix

 end
```

Error message.

```
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure S, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, 
an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must 
be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? See this blog post for reasons you should get in the habit of using statement terminators: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx And also this one about using schema prefix (especially valid for user-defined functions): https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Comment: I am still getting the below error after placing the ; for the diclaration before CTE.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure S, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: What does this yield? `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID();`

Comment: That error is because your missing a ; to fix: `;WITH SearchTerms(Term) AS ...`  - what do you mean *more that 1 suffix*? can you provide a sample input & desired output

Comment: @Alex there is also a semi-colon that *shouldn't* be there at the end of the CTE declaration, and what follows should be SELECT not SET (as I pointed out in "some other user's" question linked above.

Comment: You need to explain what "it does not work" means. What do you want returned if the value passed in is `' D.O M.D. II '` or even `' D.O. '` (which matches on two of your term values)?

Comment: @Aaron :Could u please help me to write that select insted of set. As i am new in learning sql server , i dont know to do it.

Comment: @Alexk : even after updating the code with ;. I have got some errors.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : If i pass a name having two suffixes, i should get both. for example. 'TERRY ALLEN MD III' i should get both MD and III.

Comment: How is anybody going to know what "some errors" are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it now, you have a semi-colon at the *end* of your CTE declaration. You can't do that since that terminates the statement. Try this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.S(@Name varchar(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Suffix VARCHAR(25);

    WITH SearchTerms(Term) AS 
    (
      SELECT ' I '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' II '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' III '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' MD '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' M.D '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' M.D. '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' D.O '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' D.O. '
      UNION ALL SELECT ' DO '
    )
    SELECT @Suffix = Term 
        FROM SearchTerms 
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Term, ' ' + @Name + ' ') > 0;

    RETURN (LTRIM(RTRIM(@Suffix)));
END
GO
```

**EDIT** based on new information, here is a table-valued function that returns all results:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.T
(
    @Name VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT 
            Term = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), LTRIM(RTRIM(Term)))
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Term = ' I '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' II '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' III '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' MD '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' M.D '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' M.D. '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' D.O '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' D.O. '
            UNION ALL SELECT ' DO '
        ) AS Terms
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Term, ' ' + @Name + ' ') > 0
    );
GO

SELECT Term FROM dbo.T('Terry Allen MD III');
```

Comment: @Martin Well, it won't fail per se, it will just pick one arbitrary matching Term. If he wants to return multiple matches then it needs to be either a table-valued function or some kind of concat.

Comment: @Martin Yes I got rid of the subquery (not for that reason but simply because it was redundant).